can we use jakarta.jakartaee-api version 8.0.0 with springboot 3.0.1.0.1 and openjdk 17
I have a legacy project which is using legacy servlets but I need to migrate it. With minimal changes is it alright to use  jakarta.jakartaee-api version 8.0.0 with springboot 3.0.1.0.1 and openjdk 17 ?
I am trying to use ServletRegisterationBean but it fails to compile with the error below.
constructor org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean.ServletRegistrationBean(jakarta.servlet.Servlet,java.lang.String...) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (argument mismatch; com.example.MyServlet cannot be converted to jakarta.servlet.Servlet


No you cannot. SPring Boot 3 is JakartaEE only and requires the new namespace which is JakartaEE 9 and up. So no you cannot use Spring Boot 3 with JakartaEE 8 as that effectivly is still JavaEE (using the javax.* namespace and not jakarta.* namespace). So  change your servlets to use the proper interfaces from the jakarta package
